# Get routing parameter in loadUserByUsername in UserRepository

Tags: php, symfony

Hey stackoverflow community,

i want to access a route parameter in my UserRepository. Is there any option to do this?

**1. Open Login Page**

There are multiply instances. If you open instance *exampleInstance* you can only login if you are registered in this instance.

```
http://mywebpage.com/exampleInstance
```

**2. Get User in UserRepository**

The user is loaded if he is registered in the called instance.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {        
        $instanceName = ...

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->join('u.instance', 'i')
            ->where('i.name = :instanceName AND u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('instanceName', $instanceName)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

I tried to get the parameter with *request* and *session* but i can't access this services.

I followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user) tutorial to implement the UserRepository.

Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject the request stack service into your user provider.  This is a bit tricky because you don't have access to your repository's constructor so you need to use setter injection.  Something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class UserRepository
{
    public function setRequestStack(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {        
        $request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest();
        ...
}
// services.yml
my.user_provider:
    class: 'MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository'
    factory: ['doctrine.orm.entity_manager','getRepository']
    arguments:  
        - 'MyBundle\Entity\User'
     calls:
         - ['setRequestStack', ['@request_stack']]
```

That should pretty much do it.  If it feels a bit hackish then it is.  Setter injection should be used sparingly.

I don't care for having the repository implement the load user interface.  I think it is a bit cleaner to have your own user provider class and inject the repository as well as the request stack into it.  But in the end you get the same results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That helped me a lot :)